# Make correct rebound of one SKShapeNode from others SKShapeNodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, physics

I am creating a small game and learning Spritekit physics. I have a SKScene where I place 4 borders on edge of screne (left, right, upper, bottom. Making a square). Beetwin them I have a circle SKShapeNode and i move it with velocity(dx:200, dy:200). I want my shapenode to rebound from borders like in a real world forever. So if it moves to right border with velocity(dx:200, dy:200) its rebound by X axis, from upper border by Y axis.
I think about how to do this and i thought i got it. I created some code but it doesn't work correctly after series of rebounds.

```
public var redLaserTexVert = SKTexture()

public var redCircle = SKShapeNode()
public var redCircleObject = SKNode()

public var redLaserTex = SKTexture()

public var redLaser = SKSpriteNode()
public var redLaserObject = SKNode()

public var redLaser2 = SKSpriteNode()
public var redLaserObject2 = SKNode()

public var redLaser3 = SKSpriteNode()
public var redLaserObject3 = SKNode()

public var redLaser4 = SKSpriteNode()
public var redLaserObject4 = SKNode()

public var greenCircle = SKShapeNode()
public var greenCircleObject = SKNode()

public var dx = Int()
public var dy = Int()

public var plusX = 200
public var minusX = -200

public var plusY = 200
public var minusY = -200

struct collision {
    static let circleBody: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
    static let redLaser1: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    static let redLaser2: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
    static let redLaser3: UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
    static let redLaser4: UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
    static let greenCircle: UInt32 = 0x1 << 5
}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        greenCircle = SKShapeNode.init(circleOfRadius: self.frame.width/9)
        greenCircle.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        greenCircle.fillColor = UIColor.green
        greenCircle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.frame.width/9)
        greenCircle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        greenCircle.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        greenCircleObject.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collision.greenCircle
        greenCircle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = collision.redLaser1 | collision.redLaser2 | collision.redLaser3 | collision.redLaser4
        greenCircle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = collision.redLaser1 | collision.redLaser2 | collision.redLaser3 | collision.redLaser4
        greenCircleObject.addChild(greenCircle)
        self.addChild(greenCircleObject)
        greenCircle.name = "greenCircle"

        dx = plusX
        dy = plusY

        greenCircle.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy)

        redLaserTex = SKTexture(imageNamed: "redLaserRay")
        redLaserTexVert = SKTexture(imageNamed: "redLaserRayVert")

        redLaser = SKSpriteNode(texture: redLaserTex)
        redLaser.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height/12)
        redLaser.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.minY+10)
        redLaser.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: 10))
        redLaser.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        redLaser.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        redLaser.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collision.redLaser1
        redLaser.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = collision.greenCircle
        redLaser.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = collision.greenCircle
        redLaserObject.addChild(redLaser)
        self.addChild(redLaserObject)
        redLaser.name = "leftLr"

        redLaser2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: redLaserTex)
        redLaser2.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height/12)
        redLaser2.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.maxY-10)
        redLaser2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: 10))
        redLaser2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        redLaser2.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        redLaser2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collision.redLaser2
        redLaser2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = collision.greenCircle
        redLaser2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = collision.greenCircle
        redLaserObject2.addChild(redLaser2)
        redLaser2.name = "upLr"
        self.addChild(redLaserObject2)

        redLaser3 = SKSpriteNode(texture: redLaserTexVert)
        redLaser3.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width/6, height: self.frame.height)
        redLaser3.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.minX+10, y: self.frame.midY)
        redLaser3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 10, height: self.frame.height))
        redLaser3.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        redLaser3.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        redLaser3.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collision.redLaser3
        redLaser3.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = collision.greenCircle
        redLaser3.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = collision.greenCircle
        redLaserObject3.addChild(redLaser3)
        redLaser3.name = "bottomLr"
        self.addChild(redLaserObject3)

        redLaser4 = SKSpriteNode(texture: redLaserTexVert)
        redLaser4.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width/6, height: self.frame.height)
        redLaser4.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.maxX-10, y: self.frame.midY)
        redLaser4.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 10, height: self.frame.height))
        redLaser4.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        redLaser4.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        redLaser4.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collision.redLaser4
        redLaser4.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = collision.greenCircle
        redLaser4.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = collision.greenCircle
        redLaserObject4.addChild(redLaser4)
        redLaser4.name = "rightLr"
        self.addChild(redLaserObject4)  
    }

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
        var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()

        if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "greenCircle" {

            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            secondBody = contact.bodyB }
        else {

            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            secondBody = contact.bodyA }

        if firstBody.node?.name == "greenCircle" && secondBody.node?.name == "rightLr" {

            if dx == plusX && dy == plusY {
                dx = minusX
                dy = plusY
                greenCircle.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy)
            }

            if dx == plusX && dy == minusY {
                dx = minusX
                dy = minusY
                greenCircle.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy)
            }

        }

        if firstBody.node?.name == "greenCircle" && secondBody.node?.name == "upLr" {
            if dx == minusX && dy == plusY {
                dx = minusX
                dy = minusY
                greenCircle.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy)
            }

            if dx == plusX && dy == plusY {
                dx = plusX
                dy = minusY
                greenCircle.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy)
            }
        }
        if firstBody.node?.name == "greenCircle" && secondBody.node?.name == "bottomLr" {
            if dx == plusX && dy == minusY {
                dx = plusX
                dy = plusY
                greenCircle.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy)
            }

            if dx == minusX && dy == minusY {
                dx = minusX
                dy = plusY
                greenCircle.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy)
            }
        }

        if firstBody.node?.name == "greenCircle" && secondBody.node?.name == "leftLr" {
            if dx == minusX && dy == minusY {
                dx = plusX
                dy = minusY
                greenCircle.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy)
            }

            if dx == minusX && dy == plusY {
                dx = plusX
                dy = plusY
                greenCircle.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy)
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    //   greenCircle.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 200, dy: 200)

        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to ensure that all the code you post in your question is relevant to that question. Do not put excess line breaks and empty functions in your question. it makes it harder to read the code

Comment: Ok! I understand.

Comment: do the redLaser objects need to be in this code? are you just testing this functionality with greenCircleObject? If they don't need to be there you should edit your question and remove them

Comment: they need becose i wont to rebount from them.